# Laravel Pagination with Ajax or without page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, pagination

I have a web application where pagination is important, and most of the functionality is processed through Ajax so that I can make it as smooth as possible.

I'd like to still use Laravel's pagination function (or class) where `?page={number}` is how the user paginates through `n` amount of items, but is it possible to do this without page reload? I can only imagine pain and agony trying to do it with Ajax from scratch, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I tried searching but to no avail, I also tried searching with an array of dissimilarly constructed sentences that would have led to the same question, so I don't know where else to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: its not that hard to do it with ajax

Comment: Could you please further explain?

Comment: you need a costom route and controller function to select data using skpi and limit,from your front-end you send the page number and the elements per page and in the controller you calculate the next page elements that the select to bring to the front

Comment: That's what my last resort is, but I'm just wondering if there is an easier way? Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: you can use datatables